# How to read \vartheta and vocally distinguish it from \theta?

Tags: math-mode, greek, report

I am going to vocally report my paper.

I have used both `$\vartheta$` and `$\theta$` in the equations.

How should I read `$\vartheta$` and vocally distinguish it from `$\theta$`.

Comment: As you read: *vartheta* and *theta*.

Comment: This looks off-topic to me (nothing to do with TeX) but also: `\vartheta` and `\theta` are _the same letter_ and are only _stylistic_ differences, you are not supposed to use both in one document.

Comment: Is vartheta a common known pronunciation for the greek letter `$\vartheta$`. Too bad this form does not support latex math.

Comment: Did you know that if you enclose code snippets between grave accents, it will display the text as inline code, such as `$\vartheta$`?

Comment: Off topic, but I would suggest "curly theta"

Comment: @AndrewSwann Wow. "Curly theta" sounds like a very good idea! Intuitive and understandable!

Comment: @JosephWright You're perfectly right, but unfortunately there are several authors that use both `\vartheta` and `\theta`, maybe also `\varphi` and `\phi` or, the worst of the lot, `\varepsilon` and `\epsilon`. Voted for closing as OT.

Comment: In talks to mathematicians or physicists, I call it "vartheta", because they know TeX. In talks or lectures to undergraduates (even Greek ones), I never use both theta and vartheta in the same talk, because they don't know TeX.

Comment: Same for varpi and pi. Some Greeks call p, \varpi and \pi all "pee", insisting that because they invented the letters, they get to invent how to pronounce them. But the pronunciation in mathematics (computer science, engineering, physics, ...) is not the same thing as in ordinary Greek language, so we are free to develop a more useful pronunciation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off topic, but I would suggest "curly theta".

Comment: good call -- that's the traditional proofreader's term.